# How to extract an Android app's log messages at runtime?

Tags: android

If my app goes haywire in the field, what are some diagnostic resources that the app can collect at runtime? Is there a way to access all the Logger message our app generated (i.e. via Log.e())?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the command "adb logcat" to view android debug logs

Comment: I think he means "extracting" the log from his program, rather than from the development machine.

Comment: Then why is this the accepted answer? The java api question led me here, but this is not useful info.